# pause a countdown timer within a while statement

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a loop that is started and paused when a variable is changed by clicking a button and a stop button stops the loop altogether. I can start/pause and stop the loop with the buttons I have assigned.  In that loop, I need a countdown timer.  That countdown timer also needs to pause when the main loop is paused, keep up with where it was at, and restart at that point when the main loop is unpaused but everything is froze until the countdown timer is finished.

```
class MYmain(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18,     weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.geometry("800x600+0+0")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames["mainframe"] = mainframe(parent=container,     controller=self)
        self.frames["mainframe"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("mainframe")


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.place(x=0, y=368, width=800, height=232)
        frame.tkraise()


    def shutdown(self):
        self.destroy()


    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MYmain()
    app.mainloop()

#I also have my main form
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
import sys
import time


class mainframe(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.running = False
        self.aboutToQuit = False
        self.someVar = 0

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Handheld page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        font18 = "-family {Segoe UI} -size 18"
        frame_top_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_top_left.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=0.363, relwidth=0.456)
        frame_top_left.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_top_left.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame_top_left.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_top_left.configure(background="#3f53d8")
        frame_top_left.configure(width=365)

        frame_cmd = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_cmd.place(relx=0.456, rely=0.0, relheight=0.363, relwidth=0.544)
        frame_cmd.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_cmd.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame_cmd.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_cmd.configure(background="#31d80f")
        frame_cmd.configure(width=445)

        frame_score = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_score.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.242, relheight=0.138, relwidth=1.0)
        frame_score.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_score.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame_score.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_score.configure(background="#d81838")
        frame_score.configure(width=800)

        frame_bat = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_bat.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.379, relheight=0.495, relwidth=0.256)
        frame_bat.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_bat.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame_bat.configure(relief='groove')
        frame_bat.configure(background="#3f53d8")
        frame_bat.configure(width=125)

        frame5 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame5.place(relx=0.256, rely=0.38, relheight=0.495, relwidth=0.744)
        frame5.configure(relief='groove')
        frame5.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame5.configure(background="#ffffff")
        frame5.configure(width=125)

        button1 = tk.Button(frame5)
        button1.place(relx=0.444, rely=0.296, height=42, width=98)
        button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        button1.configure(pady="0")
        button1.configure(text='''Quit''')
        button1.configure(width=98)
        button1.configure(command=self.quitme)

        buttont1 = tk.Button(frame5, text="stop comm loop",
                         command=self.toggledoquit)
        buttont1.place(relx=0.444, rely=0.496, height=42, width=90)

        buttontt1 = tk.Button(frame5, text="set pause (attr)",
                         command=self.togglesetattr)
        buttontt1.place(relx=0.244, rely=0.496, height=42, width=90)


        frame6 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame6.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.867, relheight=0.142, relwidth=1.0)
        frame6.configure(relief='groove')
        frame6.configure(borderwidth="2")
        frame6.configure(relief='groove')
        frame6.configure(background="#ced83c")
        frame6.configure(width=125)

        self._attr = False
        self._doquit = False


def doloop(self):
    #print(self.aboutToQuit)
    while not self.aboutToQuit:

        self.controller.update() # always process new events

        if self.running:
            # do stuff
            print(str(self.someVar) + " Send")
## THE ISSUE IS HERE
##          t=15
##          while t > 0:
##                if self.running:
##                    print(t)
##                    t -= 1
##                    time.sleep(.1)
##                else:
##                    time.sleep(.1)

            time.sleep(1)
            self.someVar += 1

        else: # If paused, don't do anything
            time.sleep(.1)

def quitme(self):
    self.toggledoquit()
    self.controller.shutdown()

def togglesetattr(self):
    if self._attr == False:
        self.attr=True
    else:
        self.attr=False

def toggledoquit(self):
    self.doquit = True


@property
def attr(self):
    return self._attr

@attr.setter
def attr(self, value):
    self._attr = self.attr
    self.running = not (self.running)
    if value == True:
        self.doloop()
    else:
        return

@property
def doquit(self):
    return self._doquit

@doquit.setter
def doquit(self, value):
    self.running = False
    self.aboutToQuit = not (self.aboutToQuit)
    self.someVar=0


def stopme(self):
    if self._attr==True:
        self.togglesetattr
    self.aboutToQuit = not (self.aboutToQuit)
    self.someVar=0
```

If I comment out the code as above, it works fine but as soon as I uncomment and add back in the countdown code, it will freeze until that countdown is done before I can freeze or stop the main loop.  It also needs to stop altogether when the main loop is stopped. The timer will eventually be put as label text.

I added:

```
if self.someVar == 5:
    self.toggledoquit()
    print(str(self.someVar) + " Send")
    self.time_var.set(15)
    self.countdown()
```

to the ##issue is here area then added the def:

```
def countdown(self):
temp = int(self.time_var.get())
temp -= 1
self.time_var.set(temp)
if ((temp >= 0) and (self.running==True)):
    print(self.time_var.get())
    self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

My global flag is the self.running (which works on the doloop)

Comment: You probably need [Threads](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html) to execute things in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using `time.sleep()`. Tkinter runs inside a loop so calling a function like sleep freezes the loop. To get around this use tkinters after function. Here is a basic countdown timer.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
time_var = tk.StringVar(root, value=10)

flag = False
def countdown():
   global flag
   temp = int(time_var.get())
   temp -= 1
   time_var.set(temp)
   if temp >= 0 and not flag:
      root.after(1000, countdown)  # This is where the function is called again. Time is in miliseconds

def stop_timer():
    global flag
    flag = True

def start_timer():
    global flag
    flag = False
    countdown()

tk.Button(root, text='start', command=start_timer).pack(side='bottom')
tk.Button(root, text='pause', command=stop_timer).pack(side='bottom')

time = tk.Label(root, textvariable=time_var)
time.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now you can improve this a lot. But it gives a basic idea of how to manage things simultaneously with tkinter.

Comment: I put that as a def countdown() as you said, then in my main loop call the countdown, but when my main loop pauses the countdown still does not pause. How do I implement this to solve the stated problem?

Comment: I will add a basic pause function in the answer. I would use a sentinel flag to stop the timer.

Comment: my root.after(1000, countdown) is not doing the 1000, it is instant.

Comment: Okay, yours actually goes to -1, and it works as far as timing.  When I add in the same code to my code, it ignores the 1000 AND the if compare. Mine will just continue to go negative.

Comment: I cant help you much more unless you post some new code with the parts that you have edited in.

Comment: added what I did to the end of the original post. My original code I posted runs if you want to try that then add in yours.